# Add Click event on an image using Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and I'm trying to add a click event on an image.
There are no errors in the console and the program runs ok in the browser, but I cannot trigger the click event.

Here's my code:

```
private spinner: HTMLImageElement = new Image(); 
//Also tried to initialise like this:
//private spinner: HTMLImageElement; 
//this.spinner = document.createElement("img");

this.spinner.src = "graphics/image_name.png"

this.spinner.addEventListener("click", this.test);
//Also tested this:
//this.spinner.onclick = this.test;
```

Any help would really be appreciated, because I can't find anything online that explains what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is this.test?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. It's just a function that changes a text element. I made it to check if the event works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1. In typescript, you cannot have attribute declarations (like `private spinner: HTMLImageElement;`) and method calls (like `this.spinner.addEventListener(`) on the same level (in the class scope) - The latter needs to go to some method. (I'm just going to assume that it was a `class`, which you wanted, though I'm not entirely sure. If you actually wanted this within a normal function, then you may not use `private` at all).
2. The spinner you're creating needs to be attached to the DOM somehow (e.g using `document.body.append(this.spinner)` - but I guess you just didn't copy that part to your StackOverflow question or otherwise you wouldn't see the image in the first place.
3. Passing `this.test` to `addEventListener` directly - like you did - *would* work, but usually isn't a good idea, as you would then not be able to access attributes from within your method `private test() { //... }`.) - To solve that, use an arrow function instead - e.g.: `() => this.test()` instead.

Here's a working sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jriy5b?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

I just added the code for the event listener in the class' constructor, but of course you could use it in any method you like.

Comment: Thank you so much for the working example. :D 
Yes, I did remove some of the code structure, which, in retrospect, I should have included.